# While loop through last td in each tr and conditional hide whole row

Tags: jquery

I have a table that has a list of data in it. For example it has a data like in the picture below. I want to hide any row that shows $0.00 under total's column. I wrote below jQuery to loop through and display alert for each last td in row, I wasn't able to accomplish that.

How can I make jQuery go through last column in this and check if field has $0.00 value hide it's whole row?

For example, in the below picture Gasoline, Retail and Wholesale should not be displayed because all of them has value of $0.00 in Totals section.

[image]

Sample jQuery I wrote

```
$('#table tr td:last-child').each(function(){
alert("abc");
})
```

Sample table code in the picture

```
<tbody class="vt-section">
            <!--Title-->
            <tr data-holder="top_title" class="top_title">
                <th class="title">Income</th>
            <th class="title thSection">July<br>2016</th><th class="title thSection">August<br>2016</th><th class="title thSection">September<br>2016</th><th class="title undefined">TOTALS</th></tr>
            <!--Data-->
            <tr data-holder="inc_food">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Food</th>
            <td undefined="">$26,542.00</td><td undefined="">$25,955.00</td><td undefined="">$26,067.00</td><td class="bold">$78,564.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="inc_non_food">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Non-Food</th>
            <td undefined="">$3,507.00</td><td undefined="">$3,020.00</td><td undefined="">$3,054.00</td><td class="bold">$9,581.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="inc_gasoline">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Gasoline</th>
            <td undefined="">$0.00</td><td undefined="">$0.00</td><td undefined="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="inc_retail">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Retail</th>
            <td undefined="">$0.00</td><td undefined="">$0.00</td><td undefined="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <tr data-holder="inc_wholesale">
                <th class="vt-label-un">Wholesale</th>
            <td undefined="">$0.00</td><td undefined="">$0.00</td><td undefined="">$0.00</td><td class="bold">$0.00</td></tr>
            <!--Totals-->
            <tr data-holder="inc_total_sales">
                <th class="vt-label-un bold">Total Sales</th>
            <td class="incTotal">$30,049.00</td><td class="incTotal">$28,975.00</td><td class="incTotal">$29,121.00</td><td class="incFinal red bold">$88,145.00</td></tr>
            </tbody>
```

Below is the part that generates the table

```
$('#resultForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var start = $('#start').val();
    var end = $('#end').val();
    var company = $('#company').val();

    // Add company and date at top
    $("#infoCompany").html(company);
    $("#infoDates").html(start+" - "+end);

    getData(start, end, company);

    // Remove $0.00 fields from the list
    $('.bold').filter(function(){
        return this.innerHTML.trim() === '$0.00';
    }).closest('tr').hide();
})
```

Who ever marked this as has an answer through another topic, I implemented that solution, still $0.00 ones come back.

Below is that interpretation.

```
  // Remove $0.00 fields from the list
    $('#table tr').each(function() {
        var $erledigtCell = $(this).find("td").last().prev();
        var $row = $erledigtCell.parent();

        if($erledigtCell.text() == '$0.00'){
            $row.hide();
        } else {
            $row.show();
        }
    });
```

Here's Ajax function of getData
/*Retrieve data via Ajax*/

```
function getData(start, end, company) {

    $.ajax({
        url : '../src/processes/pl.php',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'JSON',
        data : {
            start : start,
            end : end,
            company : company,
            method : 'massPL'
        },
        success: function (response) {
            data = response;
            addData()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: What's up with the `undefined` attributes?

Comment: I don't know where they come from.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide a table row depending on a value in one of its column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720848/how-to-hide-a-table-row-depending-on-a-value-in-one-of-its-column)

Comment: in the callback of each funcion missing parameters

Comment: what does `getData(start, end, company);` do?  can you share this code too?

Comment: Just added getData ajax function

Comment: and what does `addData()` do?  *stares down the rabbit hole*

Comment: addData has its own many lines long code that goes through adding special classes to the table and doing calculations, simply manipulating the data received. Can I added that jQuery right after addData?

Comment: Reference my answer if you would.  At some point in that process, you should reach a point where you have all the markup generated and are ready to append it to the page.  At that point you'd have to run the logic against it before applying it to the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.bold').filter(function(){
    return this.innerHTML.trim() === '$0.00';
}).closest('tr').hide();
```

Find all the bold elements that have html of $0.00, then find their parent tr, and hide them.

If you are returning html from an ajax call to reload the page, in order to avoid the flash you can perform this on the data before appending it to the page.

```
var $data = $(data);
$data.find('.bold').filter(function(){
    return this.innerHTML.trim() === '$0.00';
}).closest('tr').hide();
$data.appendTo('whatever');
```

Comment: This seems like it's working but for a second then $0.00 ones come back. I added this code after the line table was generated but still $0.00 ones coming back. I added code that does it to the actual question now.

Comment: You mean you are getting some screen flash?  Are you reloading the data dynamically?  Or do you mean on page load?

Comment: It seems like for a moment they get removed but they end up getting readded to the page. Yes this table gets loaded by Ajax through PHP query.

Comment: Then ideally you'd perform this on the markup that is returned from the ajax before appending it to the page, in order to avoid the flash.

Comment: I added that code to right after addData() function and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one-

```
$("#table tr").each(function () {
    if($(this).find("td:last-child").text() == "$0.00") {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
$('.bold').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "$0.00") $(this).parent().hide()
})
```

```js
$('.bold').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "$0.00") $(this).parent().hide()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody class="vt-section">
    <!--Title-->
    <tr data-holder="top_title" class="top_title">
      <th class="title">Income</th>
      <th class="title thSection">July
        <br>2016</th>
      <th class="title thSection">August
        <br>2016</th>
      <th class="title thSection">September
        <br>2016</th>
      <th class="title undefined">TOTALS</th>
    </tr>
    <!--Data-->
    <tr data-holder="inc_food">
      <th class="vt-label-un">Food</th>
      <td undefined="">$26,542.00</td>
      <td undefined="">$25,955.00</td>
      <td undefined="">$26,067.00</td>
      <td class="bold">$78,564.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-holder="inc_non_food">
      <th class="vt-label-un">Non-Food</th>
      <td undefined="">$3,507.00</td>
      <td undefined="">$3,020.00</td>
      <td undefined="">$3,054.00</td>
      <td class="bold">$9,581.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-holder="inc_gasoline">
      <th class="vt-label-un">Gasoline</th>
      <td undefined="">$0.00</td>
      <td undefined="">$0.00</td>
      <td undefined="">$0.00</td>
      <td class="bold">$0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-holder="inc_retail">
      <th class="vt-label-un">Retail</th>
      <td undefined="">$0.00</td>
      <td undefined="">$0.00</td>
      <td undefined="">$0.00</td>
      <td class="bold">$0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-holder="inc_wholesale">
      <th class="vt-label-un">Wholesale</th>
      <td undefined="">$0.00</td>
      <td undefined="">$0.00</td>
      <td undefined="">$0.00</td>
      <td class="bold">$0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <!--Totals-->
    <tr data-holder="inc_total_sales">
      <th class="vt-label-un bold">Total Sales</th>
      <td class="incTotal">$30,049.00</td>
      <td class="incTotal">$28,975.00</td>
      <td class="incTotal">$29,121.00</td>
      <td class="incFinal red bold">$88,145.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This just iterates over the last cell in each row (with the class bold), checks the text content of the cell, and hides the parent row if it's $0.00

Comment: This too, does the job but for a moment. Then $0.00 ones gets displayed again. Perhaps I am thinking ajax is rewriting the original content somehow after $0.00 are removed.

Comment: @Reis You're seeing the rows reappear in the snippet in my answer?

Comment: Yes I do. If I click the submit multiple times they go away for a moment and come back

Comment: That's not possible. At least not in my answer's snippet. There's nothing reloading or changing the output once the function runs.